# Arduino Pro Micro and HC-05 Bluetooth module

Tags: bluetooth, arduino-pro-micro, hc-05

I am using Sparkfun Arduino Pro Micro with an ATmega32u4(3.3v, 8MHz) on it (https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12587) and a HC-05 Bluetooth Module. I also running this on Windows 10.

I've made these connections: (same as this tutorial) with some additional for leds

Arduino Pro Micro TxD (Pin 0) -> HC-05 RxD
HC-05 TxD -> Arduino Pro Micro RxD (Pin 1)

I am following this tutorial: http://playground.arduino.cc/Learning/Tutorial01
I have two Serial ports available for the HC-05 COM30(incoming) and COM31(Outgoing). When I try to send letter 'H' in Serial monitor on COM31 the arduino ide freezes and the HC-05 flashes rapidly. When I try to send letter 'H' in Serial monitor on COM30 it sends but nothing happens as H should ideally turn on the led. The arduino pro works with a button but I would like to send the command externally as in the tutorial. I also try in processing but the same thing happens as when using the arduino serial monitor. I have been trying for a couple of days now with no idea why it is not working, I have tried adjusting baud rates and changing to Serial1 with no change.

I uploaded this to the Arduino to test the Bluetooth module:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

char val; // variable to receive data from the serial port
int ledpin = 6; // LED connected to pin 48 (on-board LED)
int ledpin2 = 5;
void setup() {
  pinMode(ledpin, OUTPUT);  // pin 48 (on-board LED) as OUTPUT
  pinMode(ledpin2, OUTPUT);  // pin 48 (on-board LED) as OUTPUT
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial1.begin(9600);       // start serial communication at 9600bps
}



void loop() {
  if( Serial1.available() )       // if data is available to read
  {
    digitalWrite(ledpin2, LOW);
    val = Serial1.read();         // read it and store it in 'val'
  } else {
    digitalWrite(ledpin2, HIGH);
  }
  if( val == 'H' )               // if 'H' was received
  {
    digitalWrite(ledpin, HIGH);  // turn ON the LED
  } else { 
    digitalWrite(ledpin, LOW);   // otherwise turn it OFF
  } 

  delay(100);                    // wait 100ms for next reading
}
```

Processing code:

```
//import class to set up serial connection with wiring board
import processing.serial.*;
Serial port;
//button setup
color currentcolor;
RectButton rect1, rect2;
boolean locked = false;
void setup() {
  //set up window
  size(200, 200);
  color baseColor = color(102, 102, 102);
  currentcolor = baseColor;
  // List all the available serial ports in the output pane. 
  // You will need to choose the port that the Wiring board is 
  // connected to from this list. The first port in the list is 
  // port #0 and the third port in the list is port #2. 
  println(Serial.list()); 
  // Open the port that the Wiring board is connected to (in this case 1
  // which is the second open port in the array) 
  // Make sure to open the port at the same speed Wiring is using (9600bps) 
  port = new Serial(this, Serial.list()[2], 9600);
  // Define and create rectangle button #1
  int x = 30;
  int y = 100;
  int size = 50;
  color buttoncolor = color(153, 102, 102);
  color highlight = color(102, 51, 51); 
  rect1 = new RectButton(x, y, size, buttoncolor, highlight);
  // Define and create rectangle button #2
  x = 90;
  y = 100; 
  size = 50;
  buttoncolor = color(153, 153, 153);
  highlight = color(102, 102, 102); 
  rect2 = new RectButton(x, y, size, buttoncolor, highlight);
}
void draw() {
  background(currentcolor);
  stroke(255);
  update(mouseX, mouseY);
  rect1.display();
  rect2.display();
}
void update(int x, int y) {
  if(locked == false) {
    rect1.update();
    rect2.update();
  } else {
    locked = false;
  }
  //Turn LED on and off if buttons pressed where
  //H = on (high) and L = off (low)
  if(mousePressed) {
    if(rect1.pressed()) {            //ON button
      currentcolor = rect1.basecolor;
      port.write('H');
    } else if(rect2.pressed()) {    //OFF button
      currentcolor = rect2.basecolor;
      port.write('L');
    }
  }
}
class Button {
  int x, y;
  int size;
  color basecolor, highlightcolor;
  color currentcolor;
  boolean over = false;
  boolean pressed = false;   
  void update() 
  {
    if(over()) {
      currentcolor = highlightcolor;
    } else {
      currentcolor = basecolor;
    }
  }
  boolean pressed() 
  {
    if(over) {
      locked = true;
      return true;
    } else {
      locked = false;
      return false;
    }    
  }
  boolean over() 
  { 
    return true; 
  }
  void display() 
  { 
  }
}
class RectButton extends Button {
  RectButton(int ix, int iy, int isize, color icolor, color ihighlight) 
  {
    x = ix;
    y = iy;
    size = isize;
    basecolor = icolor;
    highlightcolor = ihighlight;
    currentcolor = basecolor;
  }
  boolean over() 
  {
    if( overRect(x, y, size, size) ) {
      over = true;
      return true;
    } else {
      over = false;
      return false;
    }
  }
  void display() 
  {
    stroke(255);
    fill(currentcolor);
    rect(x, y, size, size);
  }
}
boolean overRect(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
  if (mouseX >= x && mouseX <= x+width && 
      mouseY >= y && mouseY <= y+height) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```